# Weird ';' missing error on XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax-error

I have declared a local variable within a class like this:

```
@interface EventDetailsViewController () {
    UIImageView *imgEvent;
    float lastHeight;
}
```

but XCode gives warning at the end of `lastHeight;`: Expected ';' at end of declaration list. I have added the ';' punctuation. What's wrong with this error?

Comment: Only Swift does not need semicolon `;`. You're using `@interface`, so you may be using Objective C.

Comment: @onmyway133 oh, but this is objective C... and I have added the semicolon...

Comment: Check that you're doing this in side `.m` file, not `.h` file

Comment: @onmyway133 yes, I do this in .m file. Actually, I have another variable declaration in the same block { } code, and it is ok. Only this has the problem. And the problem does not go away even after I completely removed the other declaration. I'll update the block code with the other declaration added.

Comment: Try doing it in the .h file and use @property.
`@property float lastHeight;`

Comment: @Lucky even though the original problem is not solved, `@property` solution works for me. I just hoped I can resort to a more 'simpler' variable and not declaring more properties. thanks.

Comment: @ChenLiYong Show some more context. Something before the code you posted in the question is likely causing the issue.

Comment: @Lucky Do not put the properties in the .h file. These are meant to be private instance variables. Don't replace private variables with public properties. If you are going to use properties to replace these ivars, at least keep them private. And BTW - as written, the posted code should work as-is. There's a problem elsewhere causing this issue.

Comment: @rmaddy the funny thing is, I can't reproduce the issue. after I returned the `float lastHeight;` declaration back to like in my question and build, there's no error, and the code works just fine...

Comment: @rmaddy Oh I never knew that! So private member variables appear in the interface of the implementation file? Makes things much easier.

Comment: @Lucky Technically it's not the interface. It's called a class extension. Notice the empty parentheses after the class name.